# WinJS listview itemtemplate navigate to another page

Tags: javascript, windows-8, microsoft-metro, winjs

I have the following issue I can't figure out. I have a pageControl with a listview. the list has an item template setup and I'm binding the list from the js script. I added an event handler when I click the item to navigate to another pageControl. The event fire up but when I do WinJS.Navigation.Navigate the second page is not loading.

**Page 1 html:**

```
    <div class="mediumListIconTextTemplate" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template">
        <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
            <!-- Displays the "title" field. -->
            <h4 data-win-bind="innerText: name"></h4>

            <!-- Displays the "picture" field. -->
            <img src="#" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" data-win-bind="alt: name; src: imageDefault" />
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="collection fragment">
        <header aria-label="Header content" role="banner">
            <button class="win-backbutton" aria-label="Back" disabled type="button"></button>
            <h1 class="titlearea win-type-ellipsis">
                <span class="pagetitle">Welcome to collection </span>
            </h1>
        </header>
        <section aria-label="Main content" role="main">

            <div id="basicListView"
                data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView"
                data-win-options="{itemDataSource : Data.items.dataSource, 
                    itemTemplate: select('.mediumListIconTextTemplate'),
                    layout: {type: WinJS.UI.GridLayout, maxRows:1}}">
            </div>

        </section>
    </div>
```

**page 1 JS:**

```
WinJS.UI.Pages.define("/pages/guitarCollection/guitarCollection.html", {
        // This function is called whenever a user navigates to this page. It
        // populates the page elements with the app's data.
        ready: function (element, options) {
            var list = document.getElementById("basicListView");
            list.itemDataSource = Data.items.dataSource;
            list.addEventListener("iteminvoked", this._itemInvoked);

            WinJS.UI.processAll();
        },

        unload: function () {
            // TODO: Respond to navigations away from this page.
        },

        updateLayout: function (element, viewState, lastViewState) {
            /// <param name="element" domElement="true" />

            // TODO: Respond to changes in viewState.
        },

        _itemInvoked: function (args) {
            var name = Data.items.getAt(args.detail.itemIndex).name;
            WinJS.Navigation.navigate("/pages/page2/page2.html", { name: name});
        }

    });
```

Comment: I figure it out. I wasn't following the correct navigation path. Since I'm using a PageControl, the page that calls to page1 was using `<a href="/pages/page1/page1.html>page1</a>´. That causes to change the top-level navigation and that page1 didn't have the reference for page2.</br> You have to be careful when using Single-page navigation and check that you're not changing the top-level page reference.<br/> I hope it's clear enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a common technique that should be used for that type of navigation noted on:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj663505.aspx

1. Create a link handler function
2. Intercept the click event of the href's to use the navigation framework instead of navigating like a normal href. Add this to your home.js

```
 linkClickEventHandler: function (eventInfo) {
            eventInfo.preventDefault();
            var link = eventInfo.target;
            WinJS.Navigation.navigate(link.href);
        }
```

and then add the following code in your ready event:

```
 // This function is called whenever a user navigates to this page. It
 // populates the page elements with the app's data.
 ready: function (element, options) {
    WinJS.Utilities.query("a").listen("click", this.linkClickEventHandler, false);
    ..
    ..
```

The href clicks will be intercepted and the navigation framework will be used - this assumes you have a navigation control in your default.js otherwise this navigate won't work as expected (because the navigate control hooks into these events)
So ensure in your default.html you have a nav control such as:

```
<div id="contenthost" data-win-control="Application.PageControlNavigator" data-win-options="{home: '/pages/home/home.html'}" ></div>
```